# Is there a way to use powershell to open an ssh session to a cisco router and run a show command extrapolate that information?

Tags: powershell, outlook, cisco, citrix

I have been tasked with something at work that requires me to use powershell or some other scripting language to parse an email and take a part of the body out of it or if there is a way to grab the concurrent user count  out of goliath for citrix users. I then need to open an SSH session to a router and run a sh-vpnsessiondb and grab the output of that command and combine it with the stuff parsed from the email. If someone can help with even a single part of the script it will go a long way for me :)

Comment: Found this: $olFolderInbox = 6
$ol = new-object -comobject "Outlook.Application"
$mapi = $ol.getnamespace("mapi")
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
$inbox.Folders.Item("Personal").Folders.Item("PROCESSED")
$msgs = $inbox.Folders.Item("PROCESSEDCOPY")
$msgs.items | Select-Object body | format-table -HideTableHeaders -Wrap # | out-file c:\body.txt 
I tested and it works for the first part. Just need to figure out the ssh part now.

Comment: Perhaps you can give us an example `body.txt`? If we can see what your parsing(can just be dummy data) we can help with the ssh part :)

Comment: Why don't you think in other way, like send trap to snmp or syslog server instated?